# Pressing a key and then perform another key

Tags: c#, console

I would like to write a small application using c#. When user presses any key, then this program performs a binding key.

For example, I press Q, then my application works with Triple Q.

Thank

Comment: Use a timer with an interval to track the triple key presses. So if the triple keys are pressed within the interval, you got your triple key press

Answer (score 1):

You can implement that without timer, like this codes:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var time = 3;
    char myKey = 'q';

    // do some things ...

    var key = Console.ReadKey().KeyChar;

    if (key == myKey)
    {
        bool ok = true;
        for (int count = 0; count < time; count++)
        {
            key = Console.ReadKey().KeyChar;
            if (key != myKey)
            {
                ok = false;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (ok)
        {
            // do my work
        }
        else
        {
            // Do some else works ...
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // Do some else works ...
    }


    Console.ReadKey();
}
```